# Can you spot 4 errors in this linked list code?

Tags: linked-list, nodes

I just got my test back and I was only able to spot 2  and our prof doesnt give us correct answers upon return.. wondering if you guys can help me spot 4 errors in this code for a linked list...

```
int main() {
  struct node 
 {
     int data;
     node * next; 
 }

// create empty list
node * list;

// insert six nodes at front of list
node *n;
for (int i=0;i<=5;i++)
{
  n = new node;
  n->data = i;
  n->next = list;
}
// print list
n = list;
while (!n) 
{
  cout << n->data << "  ";
  n = n->next; 
}
cout << endl;
```

Comment: Atleast tell us the 2 you spotted.

Comment: the main error here is reinventing the wheel...

Comment: This isn't creating a linked-list. All the new nodes point to `list` as their next element.

Comment: Are you supposed to * structs?

Comment: ...point to list which never has a value set. So every node has the terminator value for next, and list never points to anything.

Comment: @StenPetrov unlike yourself, most of us gain knowledge by learning, not by divine revelation

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- `struct node` missing `;` at the end of it's declaration
- `list` not initialized to `NULL`
- `list` isn't pointing to the head after nodes insertion
- node allocation not checked for success
- printing loop is incorrect - should be `while(n)` instead of `while(!n)`

Comment: i missed the ; and the initialization of list to NULL but i dont think the node allocation check is one of the problem but the While().

Anyway long time since i used this c++ basic stuff.

Comment: Add the while loop being wrong and you've got 5 out of 4 errors :)

Comment: also missing the closing } for the main function.

Comment: @hatchet I didn't include it because this isn't necessary the whole code posted

Answer (score 2):

you need to initialize list

```
 list = NULL;
```

you assign always n->Next to list, but never give list a value.

```
for (int i=0;i<=5;i++)
{
  n = new node;
  n->data = i;
  n->next = list;
  list=n;
}
```

it should be without the ! or it would not print anything.

```
while (!n)
```

Comment: you are inserting in the front of the list, so the begging is the last item you inserted, and list is pointing to that.

Answer (score 1):

Off the top of my head (some already noted by others...):

1. No `;` after `struct` definition
2. `list` not initialized
3. `list` assigned to every `next` pointer, yet never updated
4. `n` assigned (uninitialized) value from `list` throws away anything you have done so far (memory leak)
5. `main()` missing ending `}` (may not be an error if there's more you didn't post)
6. wrong condition on `while` loop - only loops while `n == 0`

Answer (score 0):

Error s

1.`node * list`

Since all nodes point to same pointer. They all point only to one item(It doesn't make it a list)

2.`while(!n)`

It should be while(n) or nothing will be printed

3.list is never assigned to anything

`node * list` creates an empty list but this list is not initialized to null

4.`struct node` misses semicolon ;

5.Post initialization `node * list` is still empty and going nowhere. All the nodes now point to it and code breaks down into anarchy!